# create an event on PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a table named request where i store name, last name,user_id, category amount and points. its a money request i made so amount can vary all the time.
and i have a table named user. that stores user id, category, name, last name

what i want to accomplish is create an event that triggers everyday at 23:00 and search for all user based on there category and update the table user  if it finds any user category with he following condition.

category id 1,2,3 all user at the begin are 1, if user category is 1 and points are = 4000 then update table user by changing user category to 2 example

```
<?php
$points = data->info_from_db;
$user_category = data->info_from_db;
if ($user_category == 1 && $points == 400)
{
    ///update users set category ='2'
}  
else {
    echo "no update today";
}
?>
```

this can be done by php? all i need is to first get all sum(points) of each user and their category and update if the condition is true.

Comment: Who is your hosting provider?

Comment: Your title makes me think SQL while the question is about PHP. Where do you want to accomplish this at?

Comment: You'll need a cron job.

Comment: i will like to accomplish on MySQL with an event, i used php as an example of my expression because i handle more that language, if can be done in php i will do it as well, i googled it but did not find anything near what i need, im asking for help as i dont know which is the best approach cause it need to be safe as well to avoid any injection

Comment: @Jacey Highly agree. Cron is the only way that you could accomplish this without having problems with your script running too long.

Comment: so i create my script normally on php and use cron job to execute it, how ever the sql query to select all user and sum total point for each one, how will that be

Comment: @walteralexander, if you tell me your hosting provider, I might be able to show you how the cron job is done. Then we can answer it all together, including the SQL. If you just want the SQL, let me know.

Comment: my hosting provider is server stack, and you coding will be more than well come, much appreciated.